# How can I get a filesystem label from sysfs?

Tags: c, linux, sysfs

How can I get the label of a filesystem using `/sys`? I know I can get much of the info about a block device by going to `/sys/class/block/<device>`, e.g. `/sys/class/block/sr1` for a cd that I know has the filesystem label `config`. I hunted through each item, found everything but the label.

I did dig through the `lsblk` source code, which, in turn, depends on calling `udev_device_new_from_subsystem_sysname` in `libudev`, so I went through that. It does appear to populate the property `ID_FS_LABEL_ENC`, but I cannot figure out where it takes it from in the tree, unless it is tracking it elsewhere?

I would just use `libudev`, but need to access outside of a C program.

Comment: Please, see if this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56309) helps you.

Comment: Only partially @rodrigo. It shows how data is passed, but not where it gets it. I always could run blkid, but I am trying to get data "from source". How does blkid get it in real time?

Comment: Ah, but that is easy! `blkid` uses `libblkid`! And as far as I know, [`libblkid`](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/tree/master/libblkid/src) does it the hard way: reading and parsing the bytes. I would suggest you link to `libblkid` directly, as it is part of `util-linux` so available on most systems.

Comment: I don't mind the hard way (masochist :-) ), but what does that mean? Which bytes? Where does it find them?

Comment: If you study the code there, you'll see that it opens the block device (`open("/dev/sda", ...)`) and then reads the bytes from there, having a lot of known partition types and filesystem.

Comment: Oh really *really* the hard way! I have written code to do that, do not relish doing it again.

Comment: So basically the answers are: read the raw bytes; use the CLI tools; use libblkid? Please write in the answer and I will accept it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem here is that you seem to think that the label of a volume is a kernel thing, as is the size or the free space.

But AFAIK it is not, the kernel doesn't care at all about volume labels, it is just a thing that goes from the in-disk format to user-land: there is no kernel API to get that information. If you need it, you just open the raw binary volume and read the data from there.

But then, there is the big issue that every filesystem is different, so you need special code to manage every single partition type there is. Fortunately, somebody has done the hard work, and you have `blkid`, part of `util-linux` available in most Linux distributions. If you need it, you can call the program directly, or link to the library [`libblkid`](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/libblkid) that does the hard work.

Naturally, to use `blkid`/`libblkid` you need read access to the block device, that is, root access. If you think that root access should not be needed to read a label, the people from `udev` think the same, and that is why there is a udev rule that copies the label when the filesystem is first dectected (running `blkid` of course). This is the `ID_FS_LABEL_ENC` you already know about.

Comment: This answer is correct, as @rodrigo showed. I don't "like" it, in that I wish it were simpler, but I accept it. :-)